# How to set Text View of String[] in Android?

Tags: android, string, textview

I'm a learner in Android. If button is clicked I want to display`String[]={"Rubin","Android","Steve"}` in textview.

I'm getting null pointer exception on `onClick`

Code:

```
    TextView tv;
Button b1;
    String question[]={"Rubin","Android","Steve"};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ques);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startExam);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setText(question[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat results. ALso the xml for R.layout.ques my gues is that it is failing to find the textview item.

Comment: Is the id of the `TextView` in your `ques` layout really `button1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the error

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

In TextView you are assigning command Button's id. Please check your ques.xml and see what Id you have assigned for TextView. Assign that id in Activity and your problem is solved.

Comment: I'm not genius like you ;) You have more than 10K reputation. It shows that you are a genius :))

Comment: @Asok Done! :)) and pls see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497460/how-can-i-change-views-in-layout-by-clicking-a-button-in-android