# How can I change Views in Layout by clicking a button in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, textview

[image: My Requirement]

I'm taking Questions and Answers in `String[]`.The `TextView` has questions and `RadioButton` has corresponding answers. If `Start Button` is clicked, first set of question and answers is displayed in `Linear Layout1`. If `Next Button` is clicked `LinearLayout1` is replaced by next set of question with answers and again if `Next Button`is clicked next set of question has to be replaced and vice versa. *Help me in writing code for `Next Button`*

**Note**: Only `LinearLayout 1` should be changed when clicking `Next Button`

code:

```
TextView tv;
RadioButton rb1, rb2;
Button bStart, bNext;
String question[] = { "Key Lime Pie is upcoming version",
        "Android is Middleware", "Which is latest Android version?" };
String answerA[] = { "True", "False" };
String answerB[] = { "True", "False" };
String answerC[] = { "Android 4.2", "Android 5" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ques);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView111);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startExam);
    bNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNext);
    bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setText(question[0]);
            rb1.setText(answerA[0]);
            rb2.setText(answerA[1]);
        }
    });
    bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setText(question[1]);
            rb1.setText(answerB[0]);
            rb2.setText(answerB[1]);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @RobinChander No errors... I'm not getting this String "Which is latest Android version?" when Next Button is clicked

Comment: Your `bNext` button isn't dynamic, so it will always set text to the second element in the array. You need to implement a counter, as @RobinChandler is suggesting below.

Comment: OK, I suggested something. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a logic problem.

1. Merge all the answers into a multidimensional array.
2. Keep track of the current question.
3. Use the tracking variable to get the question title in `question`.
4. Use the tracking variable to get the answers in the multidimensional array of answers. This is the first dimension of the array.
5. You read the answers in that dimension and display them in `rb1` and `rb2`.

By using what you have there you will have problems extending that code. After all, are you really going to create a new variable for each different set of answers? It does not make any sense. A multidimensional array works.

However... although you can improve your arrays structure and use an `int` to keep track of the current displayed question (and thus increment it to get the next question after pressing the `bNext`), I suggest you try to create more meaningful objects, like a `Question` class, with relevant members (`title`, `optionA`, `optionB`, whatever...), especially because it looks like you're using this code to learn how to program a quiz-styled application.

Then you can create various questions and iterate through then.

But is that the issue there? No. The problem is keeping track of questions and answers. Use a multidimensional array with a tracking variable.

**// edited:** OK, I'm going to suggest something very quick for you:

```
static String[] questions = new String[] { "Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3" };
static String[][] answers = new String[][] {
        {"Answer 1.a", "Answer 1.b"},
        {"Answer 2.a", "Answer 2.b"},
        {"Answer 3.a", "Answer 3.b"},
    };
int pos = -1;

void showNextAnswer() {
    pos++;
    tv.setText(questions[pos]);
    rb1.setText(answers[pos][0]);
    rb2.setText(answers[pos][1]);
}

bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showNextAnswer();
    }
});

bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showNextAnswer();
    }
});
```

As you can, both buttons do the same thing, so it's probably better to only use a next button.

Comment: Thanks but Its showing error on this line `pos++` that `The final local variable pos cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Define `int pos;` and assign the `-1` value inside the `onCreate`, before all other assignments and button set ups. My bad, completely missed that. :)

Comment: yeah done with it! its working :) All the questions completed and again I pressed `NextButton` its showing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. How to solve this?

Comment: Well.... I didn't implement the array boundary checks, I thought you would do it yourself. Just change the shownextquestion method there to include an if check and do something if pos is bigger than the amount of questions (check that after pos++). It's not that difficult. If you don't understand am exception, Google it. :)

Comment: And please remember to not fall victim of an "off by one" error. The pos variable should only go up to the amount of questions minus one. So, technically speaking, you should not fill the views if pos is >= number of questions. You get that error because the code tries to access the array in a position that does not exist.

Comment: I have done this :) `if(pos>3)` then,`Toast` a message `else` `pos++` :) Its working! and one more question for you that why we are assigning `pos` to `-1`. I mean this line `int pos = -1;`

Comment: OMG!! Help!! I did something wrong in code. its not working now :( I dont know what changes I made... and here is my full code http://pastebin.com/0XQWMg7S

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help you more, but I am away from my computer these days (only smartphone access to check stuff). I thank your recognition, but please don't feel pressured to accept or not my answer, as I'm not here in stackoverflow for the credits. But anyway, I managed to find a computer here where I am to edit your pastebin and post it for you. I can't double check for compile errors (no IDE in this computer), but I don't think there is any. Basically, your error was putting the void definition inside onCreate. It's not there, it's outside, in the class. http://pastebin.com/4iBKjh2D

Answer (score 0):

Create a single array for answers. And declare tracking variables for questions and answers as:

```
  String answer[] = {"True", "False" , "True", "False", 
                     "Android 4.2", "Android 5" };
  int current = 0; // this is your new variable
  int ans = 1;     // this is initialized to 1, because 
                   // I assumed your first question and answer
                   // is displayed with the press of start button
```

Change your next button listener to this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        current ++;
        if(current < question.length){
            tv.setText(question[current]);
            rb1.setText(answer[ans+=1]);
            rb2.setText(answer[ans+=1]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You still need to iterate the answers (i.e., `rb1` and `rb2`). Otherwise, you'll always have the same answers for each question, which is not the case.

Comment: Showing error in ` if(current < question.length())` that Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]

Comment: fixed the error u mentioned!! I accidently called string length() method on array.
I agree with @DavidCesarino, I din't notice what he mentioned.
I have edited my answer addressing his concern as well.